# JDBC CallableStatement: Aplicação trava ao chamar procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Quando executo uma *procedure* pela aplicação ele trava, porém no banco executa normal.

Esta é a forma que uso para chamar a *procedure*:

```java
public int incluir(TOCompra compra) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = BancoDados.getConexao().prepareStatement(INSERIRSQL, new String[]{"ID"});
        ps.setInt(1, compra.getId());
        ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(compra.getData().getTime()));
        ps.setBigDecimal(3, compra.getValorTotal());
        ps.setBigDecimal(4, compra.getDesconto());
        ps.setBigDecimal(5, compra.getValorLiquido());
        ps.setString(6, compra.getStatus());
        ps.setInt(7, compra.getFornecedor().getId());
        ps.setInt(8, compra.getFuncionario().getId());
        ps.setInt(9, compra.getFormaPagamento().getId());
        ps.setString(10, compra.getObservacao());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            rs.next();
            idCompra = (int) rs.getLong(1);
        }

        if ("F".equals(compra.getStatus())) {
            try (CallableStatement ctsmt = BancoDados.getConexao().prepareCall(PROCEDURE_COMPRA_ESTOQUE)) { //"{CALL COMPRA_ESTOQUE(?,?,?)}"
                ctsmt.setInt(1, idCompra);
                ctsmt.setString(2, "F");
                ctsmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return idCompra;
}
```

Eis o código da *procedure*:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COMPRA_ESTOQUE(COD_COMPRA NUMBER,STATUS VARCHAR2) IS
   QUANT NUMBER;
   PROD NUMBER;
   BEGIN
       IF STATUS = 'F' THEN
       BEGIN
           FOR ITEM IN (
               SELECT ITEMCOMPRA.QUANTIDADE, ITEMCOMPRA.PRODUTO_ID
               INTO QUANT, PROD FROM ITEMCOMPRA,PRODUTO
               WHERE COMPRA = COD_COMPRA AND ITEMCOMPRA.PRODUTO_ID = PRODUTO.ID AND PRODUTO.CONTROLA_LOTE = 'NAO'
           ) LOOP
               UPDATE PRODUTO SET ESTOQUE = ESTOQUE + ITEM.QUANTIDADE
               WHERE ID = ITEM.PRODUTO_ID;
           END LOOP;
       END;
   END IF;
END; /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- O primeiro probleminha que vi foi que havia um `}` faltando em algum lugar. Coloquei o `}` que estava faltando (assumi que é antes do bloco `catch`, no final do `try`).
- Um outro probleminha bobo que vi foi você comparar `String`s com `==` ao invés de usar o `equals`. Mas esse problema é simples de se arrumar.
- A variável `idCompra` não está declarada no código que você deu. Vou assumir que é uma variável local. Se ela não for uma variável local, então isso provavelmente está errado porque ela provavelmente deveria ser.

Bem, assumindo que o método `BancoDados.getConexao()` sempre traga uma nova conexão, veja o seguinte:

- Primeiro, se o método `BancoDados.getConexao()` sempre criar uma nova conexão quando for chamado, então para cada chamada a este método você cria uma nova conexão. Como você chama este método duas vezes, você terá duas conexões para fazer a sua operação, onde a primeira executará a SQL do `INSERIRSQL` e a segunda a SQL do `PROCEDURE_COMPRA_ESTOQUE`.
- Eu não sei exatamente o que há na sua SQL do `INSERIRSQL`, mas se ambas as conexões forem manipular o mesmo registro no banco de dados, para garantir a consistência e evitar conflitos entre as duas conexões, o banco de dados fará a segunda transação esperar o término da primeira.
- Entretanto, como ambas as transações ocorrem na mesma thread, uma vez que o banco de dados faz a segunda transação esperar o término da primeira, a thread em execução será colocada para dormir enquanto a primeira transação não finalizar. Ocorre que essa é a mesma thread que gerencia a primeira transação, e como resultado ela nunca finalizará. **O seu programa entrará em [deadlock](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)!**

Para arrumar todos esses seus problemas com a conexão:

- Você deve garantir que apenas uma conexão será utilizada.
- Tenha certeza de fechar os objetos `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet` e `CallableStament` adequadamente. A melhor forma de fazer isso é usando a sintaxe *try-with-resources* do Java 7 ou superior. Evite manter tais objetos em uso por tempo maior do que o necessário a menos que você tenha uma forte razão para fazer isso, e no seu caso você não tem.
- No `CallableStatement`, quando há parâmetros do tipo *out*, você deve registrá-los de forma adequada a fim de ler os dados devolvidos pela *procedure*.

Desta forma, aplicando as modificações pertinentes ao seu código à luz do explanado, o seu código fica mais ou menos assim:

```java
public class DAOCompra {

    private static final String PROCEDURE_COMPRA_ESTOQUE = "{CALL COMPRA_ESTOQUE(?,?,?)}";

    private static final String INSERIRSQL = "..."; // Coloque sua SQL de INSERT aqui.

    public int incluir(TOCompra compra) {
        int idCompra = 0;
        try (
            Connection con = BancoDados.getConexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERIRSQL, new String[]{"ID"}))
        {
            ps.setInt(1, compra.getId());
            ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(compra.getData().getTime()));
            ps.setBigDecimal(3, compra.getValorTotal());
            ps.setBigDecimal(4, compra.getDesconto());
            ps.setBigDecimal(5, compra.getValorLiquido());
            ps.setString(6, compra.getStatus());
            ps.setInt(7, compra.getFornecedor().getId());
            ps.setInt(8, compra.getFuncionario().getId());
            ps.setInt(9, compra.getFormaPagamento().getId());
            ps.setString(10, compra.getObservacao());
            System.out.println("insert sqlll " + INSERIRSQL);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                rs.next();
                idCompra = (int) rs.getLong(1);
            }

            if ("F".equals(compra.getStatus())) {
                try (CallableStatement ctsmt = con.prepareCall(PROCEDURE_COMPRA_ESTOQUE)) { //"{CALL COMPRA_ESTOQUE(?,?,?)}"
                    cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                    ctsmt.setInt(1, 195);
                    ctsmt.setString(2, "F");
                    ctsmt.execute();
                    String erro = ctsmt.getString(3); // Você decide o que fazer com isso.
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("erro de compra " + e);
        }
        return idCompra;
    }
}
```

Observe que:

- Só estou chamando `BancoDados.getConexao()` em um único local.
- Observe que registro o parâmetro *out* do `CallableStatement` com `cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);`.
- Observe também a sintaxe dos blocos `try`:

  ```java
  try (/*inicialização de um objeto que necessitará ser fechado*/) {
      // ...
      // ... trabalha com o objeto aqui
      // ...
  } // O compilador gera o código para fechar o objeto automagicamente.
  ```

Bem, eu não sei exatamente o que o seu método `BancoDados.getConexao()` faz. Se isso que eu demonstrei acima não funcionar, então edite a questão acrescentando o código deste método para podermos continuar a solucionar seu problema. Se isso funcionar, peço que aceite a minha resposta como solução do problema clicando no iconezinho verde à esquerda desta resposta.

Comment: Victor realmente os pontos que você colocou estavam corretos, muito obrigada. Porém agora o que acontece, tudo executa sem nenhum erro, porém nada acontece no banco, não atualiza nada.

Comment: @Ana Edite sua pergunta e poste o código da classe `BancoDados`.

Comment: @Bruno César atualizei a questão e coloquei a procedure do jeito que ela está rodando no banco.

Comment: @Bruno César, se puder me ajudar, porque agora não da erro nenhum.

Comment: @Bruno César é a mesma que está no código acima.